# Extracting stocks information

Tags: r

good morning. I am trying to extract the stocks data for couple of companies. I have used below code to do for a company called Godrej.

```
library(quantmod)
require(quantmod)
df1 <- as.data.frame(getSymbols("GODREJIND.NS", src = "yahoo", from = "2018-01-01", to = Sys.Date(),verbose = F, auto.assign = T))
allstocks <- fortify.zoo(GODREJIND.NS)
```

[image]

But if I want to extract for more than 1 company at once. Is there a way to do it? What I planned was, I shall put all companies in an excel file like above and then calling it

Could anyone help me in extracting all companies stocks at once

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `tidyquant` for this and pass a vector of symbols to the `tq_get` function.

```
symbols <- c("GODREJIND.NS", "ASHOKLEY.NS")
sd <- as.Date("2019-10-25")
ed <- as.Date("2019-10-31")


tq_get(symbols, 
       from = sd, 
       to = ed )
```

Comment: Thanks will try. But there are lots of companies under my list. I will have to put all companies manually in code right? Can we call an excel file having all lists?

Comment: Yes you can read in the excel file and parse the symbols programmatically into a variable. Try it out first and let us know what you tried if you have trouble.

Comment: Thanks I got it. ````asd2 <- read.csv(file.choose())```` then ````asd3 <- as.character(asd2[,1])```` and finally ````tq_get(asd3, 
       from = sd, 
       to = ed )````

Comment: Can you help in another issue. I have around 8000 companies. So I am extracting only for 2 dates. Usually in R, it takes lots of time. I am still running this code. Is there a way to put in server and then run the code? In general How do I handle this kind of issue